# Ограничить количество посещений (в секунду) сайтов ботом bing в конфигурации nginx

Tags: nginx

К сайту привязано несколько доменов.
Необходимо снизить посещение сайтов (в совокупности) ботами ПС Bing.

Как преобразовать директиву

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=100r/s;
```

чтобы ограничение действовало не по ip, а по user_agent в котором встречается подстрока "bing"?
При превышении количества запросов со стороны этих ботов выдавать ошибку с кодом 429: limit_req_status 429;

Comment: завести `map $http_user_agent $bing`

Comment: Пожалуйста, распишите это. Вообще не представляю как это сделать. Директиву map в документации читал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим что мы хотим запросы с `User-Agent` содержащие слово `bing` ограничивать 100rps независимо от IP, а все остальные запросы ограничить 100rps на IP.

Можно написать примерно такой конфиг:

```
map $http_user_agent $limit_key {
  default $binary_remote_addr;
  "~bing" 1;
}
...
limit_req_zone $limit_key zone=one:10m rate=100r/s;
```

Документация:

- https://nginx.org/r/map
- https://nginx.org/r/limit_req_zone

Comment: тут можно вместо 100r/s воткнуть переменную $rate и map-e прописать, что для bing $rate=100, а для default=9999999 и прописать эту переменную в директиве limit_req_zone? Потому что для всех остальных ограничивать не нужно.

Comment: в `rate=` нельзя использовать переменные. Но если вы не хотите ограничивать остальных, то можно просто написать `default "";` (пустую строку) и это будет то что надо потому что «Запросы с пустым значением ключа не учитываются»